# Is there any chance for this cactus?

Tags: cactus

I have this cactus cactus, but it leans heavily. The bigger it gets, the more it tends to lean. It leaned even before I repotted it, and is even worse after. Is there any saving it, or should I just get rid of it? I live in Georgia and am able to have it outside about half of the year. (I am not equipped to have indoor heat lamps or anything like that.)
[image]

Comment: Have you tried putting the sun on the other side of it?

Comment: I have tried that before, but will try it again.

Comment: it's not an overnight cure

Comment: It's definitely not a cactus. Perhaps someone more familiar with succulents will come up with an ID. It's entirely possible that this plant grows like this normally. Many cactus and succulents grow tall, then flop over and the top roots a stems-length from the original plant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like one of the Euphorbia species, probably **Euphorbia boranensis**.

Here’s an article on care: https://davesgarden.com/guides/articles/view/236

Columnar euphorbias can lean and even fall when they grow long and heavy, so if you want a cute bushy plant, you can cut cuttings from it (top half of plant, for example) and have a fresh start :)

Also, you can try and tie it to a stick and see if it will straighten with time.

Answer (score 1):

Repot it in a bigger (deeper)pot Bury a little more of the trunk and put it vertical, use a stick or other support to keep it vertical and do not overwater. It looks like a Euphorbia boranensis but mine have no spines sticking out, so it looks more like Euphorbia Glochidiata to me. You could take cuttings and start al over again,